# IF ELSE Conditions in Mysql Query - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to manage query using IF ELSE Condition.  But instead of IF ELSE I was to use cases.

I want to **GROUP BY** by taking decision on User type

Here is my query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM users
WHERE flag = 1 AND blockStatus = 0
GROUP BY
CASE userType
    WHEN 1 THEN
        jobId
    WHEN 2 THEN
        experienceId
END
```

Somehow it is fetching multiple records of same jobId or experienceId.

What is the right way to implement this kind of condition?

**SQL FIDDLE HERE :**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e3df6/1

Comment: Please provide a reason for down vote, so that I can work on it in future

Comment: I am surprised this structure even works. I think they allowed the conditional group by in case of static condition only. If you think about it, a group by statement applies to *the whole resultset* of the preceding query. Applying a *per-row* condition is contradictory.

Comment: can you use two sql query? i mean this in two steps?

Comment: @Sebas An example answer will help alot

Comment: *Somehow it is fetching multiple records of same jobId or experienceId.* Maybe because they have different userType or userType = 1 when it will group by jobId? Make a sqlfiddle with an exemple of what you want, this question is not clear in the format it is.

Comment: All I want is a conditional Group By on userType. Simple is that

Comment: You already have that. If you want to know why it is misbehaving you will have to provide more information.

Comment: I can provide a table dump

Comment: Her you go http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e3df6/1

Comment: It seems to be working as intented to me. There are 3 users with userType 1, it grouped them by jobId, two under jobId 6, one with jobId 8, you have 5 other users with userType 2, it grouped by experienceId so 3 were grouped under experienceId 4, and other 2 were grouped under experienceId 10. Your query is doing exactly what it was designed for. Whats the problem here?

Comment: Can you show the expected result for the sqlfiddle data you gave? (You have a `GROUP BY`, but also have `select *`. Are you expecting to just have two rows in the result set? And, if so, what columns? E.g. `userType` and a `count(*)` ?)

Comment: Try this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e3df6/9 it illustrates better whats going on.

Comment: hmmm yes it is already working fine. I guess i have missed something in my code. will have to trace. Basically originally its a huge query I am working on. some how it fetched repeated records. Well it means this part is working fine. thanks alot for the attention

Answer (score 1):

If you are using php to create this query then why not create your query based on the data in php:-

```
$query = ($userType==1) ? "Select * from users where flag=1 and blockstatus=0 group by jobId" : "Select * from users where flag=1 and blockstatus=0 group by experienceId";
```

Comment: I dont have any $userType

Comment: Thats because you didnt provide code. But you probably have something similar.

Comment: All I want is a conditional Group By on userType in a single query. Simple is that. I dont have any variables before this portion.

Comment: the usertype he is using is dynamic *per record*. It is not a static variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this..

```
SELECT *
FROM user
where usertype =1 group by jobid
union
SELECT *
FROM user
where usertype =2 group by experienceId
```